# Mysqli stmt bind and execute failing

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

I making a Login page using mysqli. After commenting out the if statements to find out where the error resides, the error looks to be within this block of code:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

When trying to run this script, I get a 500 error. I can't find any syntax or naming errors.

---

Here is the full script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {
  require('dbh.inc.php');

  $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];

  if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)) {
    header('location: ../admin.php?error=emptyfields');
    exit();
  } else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM adminAccounts WHERE uid_user = ? OR email_user = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      header('location: ../admin.php?error=sqlerror');
      exit();
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

      if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwd_user']);

        if ($pwdCheck == false) {
          header('location: ../admin.php?error=wrongpassword');
          exit();
        } else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['id_user'];
          $_SESSION['userUID'] = $row['uid_user'];

          header('location: ../index.php?login=success');
          exit();
        } else {
          header('location: ../admin.php?error=wrongpassword');
          exit();
        }
      } else {
        header('location: ../admin.php?error=nouser');
        exit();
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  header('location: ../index.php');
  exit();
}
```

Any help or advice would be very much appreciated

Comment: _Small note_ `session_start()` should really be done a t the top of your script

Comment: You are not showing yourself any useful errors if you are getting them so  Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Ok, I added those statements to the top of the script and got: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result() in /home/includes/login.inc.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home//includes/login.inc.php on line 26. I don't know how to fix this though. First time seeing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Found out after further testing, within my cpanel I didn't have nd_mysqli enabled. Enabling that fixed the problem. Thanks to RiggsFolly for helping